# How would you go about implementing a DTE?

Tags: x11, desktop-environment, wayland

I'm interested in implementing a simple desktop environment from the ground up as an experiment/learning experience, but I don't know where to start.

What are the entry points for this, and is there documentation on how the DTE fits into linux? I.e. what are the inputs and outputs etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to implement a Window-Manager for the Xorg server. See http://incise.org/tinywm.html

It's very hard to implement a Wayland-Compositor all by yourself. See https://swaywm.org

I don't know how difficult it is to develop a Wayland-Compositor that depends on `wlroots` (see https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wlroots/wlroots), but that's, what I would opt for, IMHO.